# Check if an attribute is a hex value using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example I have this xml:

```
<Node Name="A100" Id="0x1" Type="1" >
<First Name="First" New="A100" Val0="0" Val1="8" Val2="3" Val3="4" Val4="8" Val5="3" Val6="4">
<Second Name="N1" Val="0x7" />
<Second Name="N2" Val="10" />
<Second Name="N3" Val="NoFunction" />
<Second Name="N4" Val="0x1"/>
</First>
<Second Name="N5" Val="0xA"/>
<Second Name="N6" Val="No" />
<Second Name="N7" Val="0xFF" />
</Node>
```

I want to see just value which contains "0x". I'm using xsl:stylesheet version="1.0". Can somebody give me a suggestion ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see just value which contains "0x".

Use the `contains()` function, or - perhaps preferably - the `starts-with()` function.

---

No code given, because none was supplied.